# uninitialized constant -- model within controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actioncontroller

I have an application in which a club has_many locations. Clubs & their locations can only be edited within an admin namespace.

I am trying to pre-load the club into the controller so that all actions deal with that club only.

The routes are nested; however, in the locations controller, it does not find the `Club` model. What am I doing wrong?

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :clubs do
    resources :locations
  end
end
```

**club.rb**

```
class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :membership
  has_many :users
  has_many :locations
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

**admin/locations_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_club

  protected 

  def load_club
    @club = Club.find(params[:club_id])
  end
end
```

Also, lastly: What is wrong with my routes that it is not looking for the locations controller in admin/clubs/locations? I'm not sure if that is part of the problem.

**from rake routes**

```
    admin_club_locations POST   /admin/clubs/:club_id/locations(.:format)          admin/locations#create
 new_admin_club_location GET    /admin/clubs/:club_id/locations/new(.:format)      admin/locations#new
edit_admin_club_location GET    /admin/clubs/:club_id/locations/:id/edit(.:format) admin/locations#edit
     admin_club_location PUT    /admin/clubs/:club_id/locations/:id(.:format)      admin/locations#update
                         DELETE /admin/clubs/:club_id/locations/:id(.:format)      admin/locations#destroy
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably looks up the `Club` model within the current Admin namespace. You could try:

```
def load_club
  @club = ::Club.find(params[:club_id])
end
```

Comment: Yes, it was a namespacing issue with the model. Thanks! I figured it out immediately after I created the question. >.>